# Display the side menu in ionic using different pages

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to display the side menu in ionic, I wrote the code for side menu.

If I write all the code in a single page, it is displaying the side menu and drag is also working.

Same way, I am trying to display the side menu proving route `$stateProvider`, here the root is working and also it is going to home page without any problem. But in home page, it is displaying empty, I mean white page and I tried just wrote text using `h1` tag at that time also it is displaying white page.

My requirement is, if I click or drag the menu in home page it should open the side menu and also must be code in different files.

#### INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ionicApp">

<head>
    <title>IonicSideMenu Example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-rc.4/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-rc.4/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Module.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script src="AppCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="MenuController.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
</body>

</html>
```

**MODULE.JS**

```
var ionicInfoApp = angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic']);
```

#### CONFIG.JS

```
ionicInfoApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('/Home', {
            templateUrl: 'Home.html',
            controller: "MenuController"
        })
        .state('/Item1', {
            templateUrl: 'item1.html'
                // controller : "MenuController"
        })
        .state('/Item2', {
            templateUrl: 'item2.html'
                //controller : "MenuController"
        })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/Home');
});
```

#### AppCtrl

```
ionicInfoApp.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

    ionic.Platform.ready(function() {

    });

});
```

#### MenuController

```
ionicInfoApp.controller('MenuController', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
    $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
    }
});
```

**HOME.html**

```
<div ng-controller="MenuController">
    <ion-side-menus>
        <ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
                <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon" ng-click="toggleLeft()"></button>
                <h1 class="title">App</h1>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-side-menu side="left">
            <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
                <h1 class="title">Projects</h1>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content>
                <ul>
                    <li>Item1</li>
                    <li>Item2</li>
                </ul>
            </ion-content>
        </ion-side-menu>
    </ion-side-menus>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Side Menus should not be in your **`ionNavBar`** container. In your code , its just some things don't really work well when they are not placed in the correct place.

**home.html**

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
            <ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-back-button>
            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
            <h1 class="title">Projects</h1>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content>
            <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/item1">
                Item1
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/item2">
                Item2
            </ion-item>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

**config.js**

```
ionicInfoApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            url: '/app',
            // abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html',
            controller: 'menuController'
        })

    .state('app.item1', {
        url: '/item1',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/item1.html'
            }
        }
    })

    .state('app.item2', {
        url: '/item2',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/item2.html'
            }
        }
    });
    // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/item1');
});
```

If you need any help.Please let me know.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep the ion-side-menus directive in index.html and use ng-include to load in it the right template depending on a string variable with template url.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude

That variable could be selected in state provider, look for how to attach custom data to state objects